# findall all hyphenated words in greek text

Tags: python, regex

I have a greek text with hyphenated words every time a newline exists. For example:

```
Καλημέρα ο καιρός είναι απίστευτος σή-
μερα και θα πάμε εκδρομή. Πρέπει να ετοι-
μασουμε πράγματα για πικ-νικ.
```

I need to find the word boundaries between the character "-" only if a newline is inserted so as to remove it and move the newline character "\n" in the end of the dehyphanated word.
My result should be like this:

```
Καλημέρα ο καιρός είναι απίστευτος σήμερα
και θα πάμε εκδρομή. Πρέπει να ετοιμασουμε
πράγματα για πικ-νικ.
```

I am using regular expressions in python and my command is

```
re.findall(r'\b.*?-\n.*?\s', data, re.UNICODE)
```

to get the word between boundaries but the result is:

```
Καλημέρα ο καιρός είναι απίστευτος σή-
μερα
```

and not just the word

```
σή-μερα
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with greek characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
\b(\w+)-\r?\n(\w+)\b
```

and replace by:

```
\1\2\n
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB1tE8/1)

**Code:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b(\w+)-\r?\n(\w+)\b', re.UNICODE)

result = re.sub(p, u"\1\2\n", input)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava! It works! But could you explain what does \1\2\n mean?

Comment: Yes sure. `\1` is back-reference to 1st matched group (word before hyphen) and `\2`  is back-reference to 2nd matched group (word after hyphen and newline).

Comment: Well sorry for the question I saw the demo and I understood the substitution!Thanks a lot @anubhava!!

Comment: No issues, as long as answer works to your satisfaction and there is a clear understanding it is all good :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `re.sub` function.,

```
>>> s = '''Καλημέρα ο καιρός είναι απίστευτος σή-
μερα και θα πάμε εκδρομή. Πρέπει να ετοι-
μασουμε πράγματα για πικ-νικ.'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'-\n(\S+)\s+', r'\1\n', s))
Καλημέρα ο καιρός είναι απίστευτος σήμερα
και θα πάμε εκδρομή. Πρέπει να ετοιμασουμε
πράγματα για πικ-νικ.
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uZ8rE0/1)

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters where `\s+` matches one or more space characters. `re.sub` function will replace all the matched characters with the chars present inside the replacement part. So this  `r'-\n(\S+)\s+'` regex matches the hyphen and the following newline character as well as the word which follows that newline character . `()` called capturing group used to capture chars which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group. Here the pattern present inside the capturing group is `\S+` . So it matches as well as captures the word which follows the  newline character. You could refer the captured chars in the replacement part by specifying it's group index number.